# QT QSoundEffect Play immediately in a QThread environment?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QT project (QT Creator 4.9.2, based on QT 5.12.4) where I simulate the sound of heartbeats with varying Beats per Minute.
I created a QSoundEffect with a 200ms sample, and want to iterate the sample with a thread sleep (e.g. 200ms sample, 800ms sleep to simulate 60 BPM).

I've put everything in a separate QThread as recommended (and required, in the background I need to listen to the BPM changes).

However, it seems that the

```
 m_heartbeat.play();
```

postpones the actual playing to the end of the loop. I conclude that from further testing/debugging:

If I play test program (triggered from an UI button) with:

```
emit playSample();
emit mSecondsPause(800);
emit playSample();
emit mSecondsPause(800);
emit playSample();
```

The button pauses for a few seconds and I hear 1x the sample (but this is the sample 3 times simultaneously, what I deduce from running it with the debugger).

Also in the debugger, I can step over the play() call, wait indefinitely, but still do not hear the sample. Only after fully continuing I hear the sample (end of loop). Running without debug does not solve the issue.
Raising thread priority to Real-Time did not help either.

I selected the QSoundEffect for 'Low Latency', but apparently, I am missing something.

Questions:

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. Can I force QSoundEffect.play() immediately?
3. Do I need to signal play sample completion?
4. Could I use some mutex/semaphore/..?
5. Is the UI thread in the way?
6. Is there some nice example code that solved this issue?

Comment: Try to create a long sound iteration (1 second: sound 0.2 and silence 0.8 in 1 iteration) and run this sound with `QSoundEffect` but setting `QSoundEffect::setLoopCount`. In your example `QSoundEffect::setLoopCount(3)`. I can provide multithreading example for serial playing of effect but I face some strange behavior of `QSoundEffect` so I little confused about it. Better try long loop (with silence inside) and `QSoundEffect::setLoopCount`

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not really support my use case, I expect e.g. a heart rate of 72, and the next second a heart rate of 75, so each cycle, I need to calculate new pauses. However, I got a working example where I created an event loop where I connected to the playingChanged() signal. A bit devious, but it works.